# How to compare an element to every first element in a sublist in python?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, nested

My team member have passed me a dictionary that stores data for a menu at a specific date and time like this:

```
    storeMenu = {}
    # menu[id] MenuName,storeID,[days],[time available],[meals available]
    storeMenu[1] = ['Mon Tues Special', 1, [0, 1], [[time(9, 0), time(10, 59)]], [1, 2]]
    storeMenu[2] = ['Thurs Fri Menu', 1, [3, 4], [[time(9, 0), time(10, 59)]], [5, 4]]
    storeMenu[3] = ['Wednesday Menu', 1, [2], [[time(9, 0), time(11, 00)], [time(14, 00), time(19, 00)]], [1, 2]]
    storeMenu[4] = ['Wednesday Lunch Menu', 1, [2], [[time(11, 0), time(14, 00)]], [1, 2, 4]]

    storeMenu[5] = ['Breakfeast Menu', 2, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [[time(9, 0), time(10, 59)]], [6, 7, 8]]
    storeMenu[6] = ['Lunch and Dinner Menu', 2, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [[time(11, 00), time(20, 00)]], [9]]
```

I want to return the menu[x] if my selected time falls between the start time and end time. I have coded a function to retrieve it's start time, end time and a function to check.

```
    def getStartTime(storeMenu):
        menu = []

        for x in storeMenu:
            if(len(storeMenu[x][3]) == 1):
                result = [x, storeMenu[x][3][0][0]]
                menu.append(result)
            elif(len(storeMenu[x][3]) > 1):
                result1 = [x, storeMenu[x][3][0][0]]
                result2 = [x, storeMenu[x][3][1][0]]
                result = result1+result2
                menu.append(result)  

        return menu

    print(getStartTime(storeMenuFile))

    def getEndTime(storeMenu):
        menu = []
        for x in storeMenu:
            if(len(storeMenu[x][3]) == 1):
                result = [x, storeMenu[x][3][0][1]]
                menu.append(result)
            elif(len(storeMenu[x][3]) > 1):
                result1 = [x, storeMenu[x][3][0][1]]
                result2 = [x, storeMenu[x][3][1][1]]
                result = result1+result2
                menu.append(result)
        return menu

    print(getEndTime(storeMenuFile))


    def menuAtSelectedTime(storeMenu, sTime, selTime, eTime):
        menu = []

        for menuID in storeMenu:
            if(menuID == sTime[menuID-1][0] & menuID == eTime[menuID-1][0]):
                startTime = sTime[menuID-1][1]
                endTime = eTime[menuID-1][1]
                if(startTime < selTime < endTime):
                    result = [menuID, storeMenu[menuID]]
                    menu.append(result)
        return menu

    sTime = getStartTime(storeMenuFile)
    eTime = getEndTime(storeMenuFile)
    selTime = time(15, 00)
    print(menuAtSelectedTime(storeMenuFile, sTime, selTime, eTime))
```

However, it only prints menu[6] and not menu[3]. I believe there is something wrong in my if statement but I can't seem to figure out. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If that's how your team member is creating the menu "dictionary", you should have them reconsider the structure, because that is certainly _not_ a `dict` as far as Python is concerned. Restructuring it into an actual dictionary, with keys and everything, would make extracting the data you need pretty simple, instead of dealing with seemingly arbitrary indices everywhere.

Comment: Am I right to assume time(9,0) means 09:00. And the elements in [time available] start and end time?

Comment: @brainLoop yup, the list in [time available] represent the start time and end time, time(9,0) = 09:00

Comment: @b_c i understand where you are coming from, i've also pointed it out to my team member but they insist on using this, so i've got no choice but to make do with it

Answer (score 0):

You can use list interpretation to quickly iterate over a list and return all items matching your query. List interpretation works as such [(items to return) for (values) in (list) if (boolean statement)]. In this case I return all the indices where you have a matching condition.

```
inds = [i for i, (MenuName,storeID,days,times,mealsavail) in enumerate(menu) if any([tstart>cond and tend<cond for tstart, tend in times])]
```

Lastly, return all the menus at those indices using another list interpretation.

```
[menu[i] for i in inds]
```